# IL Calling a method with 2 array arguments using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, il

First I must aplogise for being a noob with IL.
I am having difficulty generating IL code to call a method with this signature:

```
public void CallMethod2(string name, object[] args, object[] genericArgs)
```

I am able to call a method that has a single array that looks like this:

```
public void CallMethod1(string name, object[] args)
```

using the following IL works:

```
ILGenerator ilgen = myMethod.GetILGenerator();
var il = ilgen;
MethodInfo invokerMethod = typeof(Proxy<T>).GetMethod("CallMethod1", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, method.Name);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(System.Object));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, invokerMethod);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

But then I use the following IL to try and call CallMethod2 using this IL:

```
ILGenerator ilgen = myMethod.GetILGenerator();
var il = ilgen;
MethodInfo invokerMethod = typeof(Proxy<T>).GetMethod("CallMethod2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, method.Name);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(System.Object));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(System.Object));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, 1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, invokerMethod);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

This IL with additional object[] I get an error:

Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

As you can see all i did was added the 2nd block to populate the array and call the method, it seems that by using StLoc_1 it just corrupts it.

I wrote the same method and called it normally and looked at ILDasm  and the codes seem to all tie up.

Thanks

Comment: I find it interesting that you aren't using DeclareLocal

Comment: I want to check this more, but can you please clarify the signature to myMethod, so I can repro it locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm very confused... you see: that code *shouldn't work* since you haven't actually allocated any locals; for example, here's a badly written (in that it uses unnecessary locals) multiply-by-4 method, that doesn't declare the locals:

```
    var method = new DynamicMethod("MulBy4", typeof (int),
         new Type[] {typeof (int)});
    var il = method.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0); // this usage is 
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0); // deliberately silly
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1); // this usage is 
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1); // deliberately silly
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    var mulBy4= (Func<int,int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof (Func<int, int>));
    var twelve = mulBy4(3);
```

This creates the `VerificationException`:

> Operation could destabilize the runtime.

since it is unverifiable. It is bad IL! If we change it to:

```
    var method = new DynamicMethod("MulBy4", typeof (int),
         new Type[] {typeof (int)});
    var il = method.GetILGenerator();
    il.DeclareLocal(typeof (int));
    il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
    ...
```

then **now** it works. This then leads onto an alternative to remembering the numbers - by storing and using the `LocalBuilder` that is returned from `DeclareLocal`:

```
    var method = new DynamicMethod("MulBy4", typeof (int),
         new Type[] {typeof (int)});
    var il = method.GetILGenerator();
    var multiplier = il.DeclareLocal(typeof (int));
    var result = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, multiplier);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, multiplier);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, result);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, result);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    var mulBy4= (Func<int,int>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof (Func<int, int>));
    var twelve = mulBy4(3);
```

If you are concerned that this uses the longer IL version, then you can use instead:

```
static void LoadLocal(this ILGenerator il, LocalBuilder local)
{
    switch(local.LocalIndex)
    {
        case 0: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0); break;
        case 1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1); break;
        case 2: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2); break;
        case 3: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3); break;
        default:
            if(local.LocalIndex < 256)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, (byte) local.LocalIndex);
            } else
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, (ushort) local.LocalIndex);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

along with `il.LoadLocal(multiplier);` and `il.LoadLocal(result);` (and obviously something similar for `Stloc`)

Comment: Hi Marc, All i wanted was to generate this one proxy method, my understanding of IL is not enough at this point. But I thought that the call to OpCodes.Newarr and then Opcodes.StLoc_0, creates a new array and puts the value in local variable 0 essentially this is the variable i am declaring

Comment: @Andre but... you *haven't* declared it...? but as per my comment on the question, I'm trying to repro this locally - but need to know the signature (including: static or instance, parameter-types) of your myMethod

Comment: Hi Marc, the method: MethodBuilder myMethod = tb.DefineMethod(method.Name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, method.ReturnType, typeParameters.ToArray());

Comment: I was testing with the method being generated having a signature: void Hello(object instance);

Comment: Hi Marc, You are right, I added the following lines to the IL:                 il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object[]));
                il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object[]));   This fixed it

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that these lines just before the method invocation:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
```

should be

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
```

Your arrays are in stack positions 0 and 1, not 1 and 2.

Comment: Minor note; if you use Ldloc you can also just pass the LocalBuilder value returned from DeclareLocal, IIRC; I don't know (without checking) whether this uses the short form vs the long form

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'll take your word for it. I was just going by inspection, with no real knowledge of this at all :)

Comment: John's answer was correct in the sense that I had the variable numbers wrong, i think this happened as i was trying to change various things to get it to work. But I did have 0 and 1 at a stage and still didnt work, It was only until I added the local variables as per Marc suggestion that it started to work

Answer (score 0):

I've updated @Mark's answer to cover value types as well. StoreLocal is bonus :)

```
public static void LoadLocalValue(this ILGenerator il, LocalBuilder local)
{
    switch (local.LocalIndex)
    {
        case 0: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0); break;
        case 1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1); break;
        case 2: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2); break;
        case 3: il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3); break;
        default:
            if (local.LocalIndex < 256)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, (byte)local.LocalIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, (ushort)local.LocalIndex);
            }
            break;
    }
}

public static void LoadLocalAddress(this ILGenerator il, LocalBuilder local)
{
    if (local.LocalIndex < 256)
    {
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, (byte)local.LocalIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca, local);
    }
}

public static void LoadLocalAuto(this ILGenerator il, LocalBuilder local)
{
    if (local.LocalType?.IsValueType == true)
    {
        LoadLocalAddress(il, local);
        return;
    }
    LoadLocalValue(il, local);
}

public static void StoreLocal(this ILGenerator il, LocalBuilder local)
{
    switch (local.LocalIndex)
    {
        case 0: il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0); break;
        case 1: il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1); break;
        case 2: il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_2); break;
        case 3: il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_3); break;
        default:
            if (local.LocalIndex < 256)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_S, (byte)local.LocalIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, (ushort)local.LocalIndex);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```